# Identify this bike please

Tags: frames, identify-this-bike

[image]

What kind of bike is this? Looks like it says Tornado. I love the handles - what kind are they?

Comment: Please include a photograph where the bike is the main subject and is properly illuminated.

Answer (score 5):

This is a fixie that was most likely built from a diverse set of components.

Frame and fork look like an road bike from before 1985.

The handlebar was most likely not from the same bike. It is typical for old roadsters a generation older.

Rims have eyelets and a trapezoid cross section. That would fit to 80s to 90s. The hubs have those peculiar high flanges with holes to reduce weight. That looks very much like early 80s.

Not enough detail in brakes. The style was used from 70s onward. Brake pads are new. Brake bolt seem new as well.

Brake cable outers look as old as the frame. That speaks for a home built fixed gear conversion. Shops would likely replace parts that are cheap and ugly (and possibly unsafe) to make it more attractive on storefront display.

Comment: To me the brakes look like dual pivots. They were popularized in the 90s.

Comment: My 80s single pivot 105 look somewhat similar from behind. I don't think I could spot the difference though. They seem to have old style barrel adjusters and release. Cannot see large plastic parts.

Comment: I've looked at the photo on a large screen now. As @ojs said, the rear is definitely a dual pivot brake. To me it looks very much like a recent Tektro brake (eg R317).

Answer (score 3):

Looks like an Elswick Tornado to me, all the frame features match with [this bike](http://www.camdencycles.co.uk/our-bikes/racing-bikes/elswick-tornodo/prod_864.html?catId=81) and [this one](https://www.flickr.com/photos/tovey-moulton/3747622356/in/photostream/), except for decals. Polished front tube, the fork and bands around seat tube are most likely aftermarket additions. Can't tell the year either.